# How to add external folder to Jetty's classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jetty, classpath

I am trying to add an external folder, `setup/`, to my Jetty's classpath.  I can successfully add the `setup` folder to its classpath inside of its `launch configurations` in eclipse.  I need to instead give it the `setup` folder's path as an argument to Jetty because I don't have control of the `launch configurations` when I run my project outside of an eclipse environment.  I've tried stuff like this in the XML:

```
<jvmarg value="-Dpath=${DbServer.location}/setup"/>
```

This does not do anything...  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should post the ANT xml used to launch jetty. I'm guessing the problem is the manner is which your defining the classpath, which is explicitly passed to the "java" ANT task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the setup folder is in the WAR directory, so even pointing to anything else as the classpath will not make changes to where Jetty will look for the folder. Look here for how Jetty uses its classpath:

[Jetty ClassLoading](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html)

> Classes contained within `WEB-INF/lib` or `WEB-INF/classes` have priority over classes on the parent class loader. This is the opposite of the normal behaviour of a java 2 class loader.

Comment: More specifically : http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html#adding-extra-classpaths

Answer (score 0):

As an example, to run it with the help of Maven ([jetty-maven-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html)) :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.7.v20170914</version>
            <configuration>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>8095</port>
                </httpConnector>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <extraClasspath>conf/</extraClasspath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then run your webapp with `mvn jetty:run`

At the root of my project, I have a `./conf/` directory, including some properties or xml files.

Some configuration properties for  can be found at [Configuring Your WebApp](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp), but you can find **undocumented properties** in the class `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext` or in `org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext` (its subclass).